# Is using an electric fly swatter outdoors frowned upon?

Tags: hiking, health, bugs, preparation

When hiking, occassionally there are areas with a ton of mosquitoes (near bodies of still water) or flies (near outhouses, or in the "toilet"). With bug repellent, I still get bitten a lot.

Is using an electric fly swatter in these areas frowned upon? (because it disturbs the habitat)

Comment: Perhaps try where lightweight long sleeves and pants when hiking. The less skin exposed hopefully the less biting.

Comment: Using that method, I don't think you could kill enough to make any difference even if you were swatting all day. However, your day-long frantic swatting might result in less bites just because you would be moving constantly, it would be good exercise, and might provide comic relief for fellow woodsmen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, killing bugs with an electric fly swatter is not as disturbing as you being in the woods itself.  As far as I know, the only electric bug devices that would be discouraged are the zappers that include a light that attracts moths as they kill bugs indiscriminately.  The fly swatter you are describing wouldn't be much different than using your hand to swat the bugs yourself.

Answer (score 5):

Frame challenge: trying to kill annoying mosquitoes while outside is a pointless endeavour, whether you use your hand or any kind of electric fly swatter.

There are many more mosquitoes than you will have the patience to kill, and they will just keep coming and coming and coming...

You need **passive defence** such as:

- mosquito-proof trousers, long sleeves, gloves
- mosquito net over your hat
- mosquito net to sit/sleep in (or, of course, a tent)
- insect repellent for exposed skin
- smoke/scent candles can work (to a degree)